# How can i attach something to happen on setState const

Tags: reactjs

i have

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
```

how can I add one more action to happen when firing `setItems()`, so something like (which is not valid)

```
const setItems = (items) =>{
    // do something first
    // then call the setItems
}
```

it's possible to pass it to another function first then call the actual setItems() later, but I was wondering if its possible to override the original setItems function.

Comment: You have it right, except you can't overwrite `setItems`, it just needs to be a new function name and you use `setItems` within.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an intermediate function as call setItems from that function.

```
const handleSetItems = (params) => {
    setItems (prevItems) =>{
        // do something first
        // then call the setItems
        return prevItems; // data to be set in items state
    }
    }
```

Or you can do within setter function as following

```
setItems (prevItems =>{
            // do something first
            // then call the setItems
            return prevItems; 
        })
```